# Theano TensorVariable object has no attribute get_value

Tags: python, theano

I have the following theano object:

```
train_set_x = cPickle.load(f)
print (train_set_x.type, train_set_x.get_value().shape)
>>TensorType(float64, matrix) (1000000L, 64L)
```

However, when I try to slice it then get the shape again

```
train_set_x = train_set_x[:100]
print (train_set_x.type)
>>TensorType(float64, matrix)
n_train_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
>>AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'get_value'
```

Can someone explain to me why after slicing, i get this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`train_set_x` is a theano shared variable, so you can't set it like `train_set_x = train_set_x[:100]`.

You should try using set_value():

```
train_set_x.set_value(train_set_x.get_value()[:100])
```